# How do I get a notification about a new discord DM message using an event or something else?

Tags: python, events, python-requests, discord

With using only your authorization token, not Bot. How do I listen to events about a new DM message in the discord? Maybe using an api or something else?

I tried using websockets, but it only takes messages from discord servers, but not DM messages. Maybe I'm wrong?